# A chain with more than two elements

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

A chain with two elements $0$ & $1$ is complemented as complement of $0$ is $1$ and that of $1$ is $0$.How to show that every chain with more than two elements is not complemented?

Comment: What is a 'complemented chain'?

Comment: @GitGud: I believe that the OP is trying to show that a linear order with more than two elements is not a complemented lattice.

Comment: But what have she tried so far?

Comment: If you need any help tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $C$ is a chain and $x\in C\setminus\{0,1\}$. Let $y\in C$.

- If $y\le x$, what is $x\lor y$?
- If $x\le y$, what is $x\land y$?

Comment: If y<=x then xvy=y and if x<=y than x^y=x which doesn't equals 0 or 1, sorry but I still can't relate this to the statement I want to prove.@Git Gud sorry for the inappropriate information in the question but yes, I was referring to a complemented lattice.

Comment: @Vandana: In both cases the answer is $x$. If $x$ had a complement $y$, what condition(s) would $y$ have to satisfy?

Comment: In that case x^y=0 and xvy=1, and we'll have a contradiction resulting into the proof. But what if chain C is bounded?

Comment: @Vandana: It doesn’t matter whether $C$ is bounded or not: the argument shows that if $x$ is not the top or bottom of the chain, then $x$ does not have a complement.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for clearing my concepts.

Comment: @Vandana: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @VandanaSharma if you need any help tell me I'm ready

Comment: @Functional analysis Thanks, I appreciate your support.